# Authenticating custom Umbraco controller with OWIN/OIDC against Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, umbraco, azure-ad-b2c

I am stuck.

I have a custom Umbraco controller which inherits from `RenderMvcController` and when the `Index()` action method is hit a file is returned. This works, but what I want to do is to protect it by decorating the action with an `AuthorizeAttribute` and then requiring the user to authenticate.

```
namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class MyModelController : RenderMvcController
    {
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The authentication is to be made using OWIN and OpenId Connect against an Azure AD B2C app. This also works and is tested, but in a non-Umbraco context.

I have read numerous threads and code relating to the subject, but I am struggling to integrate it within Umbraco. I have a custom startup class which inherits from `UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup`. I register a custom route to my `AuthController` and configure OIDC via `IAppBuilder.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()`.

But I need the Umbraco glue and have problems understanding how I should configure the cookies. I have checked that the startup `Configuration()` method is invoked.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class CustomOwinStartup : UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup
    {
        public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            base.Configuration(app);
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                "CustomAuth",
                "CustomAuth/{action}",
                new { controller = "Auth" }
            );
        }

        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/CustomAuth/SignUpSignIn") // TODO: What should I put here?
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                // Passing options that are tested and working
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have my auth controller which is very simple for the time being. I have no requirement to sync the auth info with Umbraco users.

```
namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
    public partial class CustomAuthController : Controller
    {
        public CustomAuthController() : base()
        {
        }

        public void SignUpSignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
                return;
            }

            Response.Redirect("/"); // TODO: Maybe this should redirect me back to original route MyModel/Index in some way
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this and try to via my attribute-decorated custom Umbraco controller I get this error:

> **Page not found**
>
> No umbraco document matches the url `'/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=MYORIGINALROUTEHTTPENCODED'`.
>   This page can be replaced with a custom 404. Check the documentation for "custom 404".

My guess is that this is because of the `<authentication mode="Forms">` setting in `Web.config`, but if I remove this or set the attribute `mode` to `"None"`, will this not impact the back-office login?

Very thankful if anyone can help me point me in the right direction!

Comment: Have you reviewed [this sample app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) that uses owin w/ b2c?

Comment: Yes, I have, that is the basis for the options object I am passing to the OIDC configurator.

Comment: To elaborate, I have gotten it to work by using the sample app, but now I want to add the same authentication layer to an existing Umbraco application which already has authentication which I would like to leave as-is. I don't need my custom auth to hook up to the front-end user store in Umbraco since I only want to do auth-then-forget. Or maybe auth-then-maybe-log. The rest of the site is public accessible.

Comment: Just to clarify, several questions: 
What should happen when a user is not logged in and tries to open Index page of MyModelController? Should he be directed to your custom login page or to umbraco one?
Do you want to live with 2 different authorization systems, your custom and umbraco? So each of them will be used for different pages?

Comment: laroslav: The user should be redirected to the Azure AD B2C login page. I can live with to authorization systems if one is for front-end (custom) and one is for back-office (Umbraco).

Comment: @Viktor, Have you managed to solve your problem? If yes I'm just interested in what way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have enough time to set up the same environment and check everything but I will give several thoughts and post several links.

To override back office login logic you don't need to create your custom auth controller or override login page. Since Umbraco uses ASP.NET Identity for authorization you need to configure it properly in the OWIN startup and it will work as you need. Then you will use Umbraco authorization tools to check if a user can hit Index action of MyModelController.

If you need to implement custom username/password check use Umbraco extension for it. See more: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Security/#replacing-the-basic-username-password-check

Also you can use Umbraco extension for Active Directory. See more: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Security/#authenticating-with-active-directory-credentials

And about AuthorizeAttribute. You're getting *not found* error cause *Authorize* doesn't know anything about OWIN and Umbraco. It redirects to the default path which is login.aspx page and it doesn't exist in the project. You can set `<authentication mode="Forms">` to `None`. It won't affect Umbraco backoffice cause it uses ASP.NET Identity for it. If you want to protect some resources you can use UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute.

See more: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Implementation/Controllers/#mvc

Anyway read more Umbraco tutorials and docs. I hope you will find answer. Feel free to ask more.

**Updated**

Try to use your own version of AuthorizeAttribute. There is an example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/

You need to override AuthorizeCore method and return needed result from HandleUnauthorizedRequest. So you can return RedirectResult to your login page or whatever you need.

You can apply it then as

```
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

**Updated 2**

If custom AuthorizeAttribute doesn't help or it doesn't work you can create your ActionFilter and put authorization logic there. Of course it's not best practice but you can at least try to do it. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(vs.98).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: I don't need to override back-office login. Simply put: I want to do authenticate an user when he or she tries to access a particular document type. I just want to know that the user is registered with my identity provider. I tried protecting the document type controller with `MemberAuthorizeAttribute` but this renders the error "This type of page is not served". I can however invoke my OAuth provider via `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge()`. Can I in some way override what `MemberAuthorizeAttribute` does when the request is not authenticated?

Comment: Unfortunatelly you can't use MemberAuthorizeAttribute  to check if a user is authorized or not. You can read more here if you want: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/53816-MemberAuthorize-Redirection#comment-186685. 

I understood your needs and will try to look more about your question.

Comment: Have you tried just to write your own custom AuthorizeAttribute? I suppose that it should work. I saw that approach at one of my previous projects. We had it for web api but for MVC it should almost the same.

Here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/

You can check your user via OWIN context and if need redirect to login page or whatever you want. 

Please write me if it helps or you need more clarifications.

Comment: I've updated my answer with clarifications about custom AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: I opted to use write a custom implementation of `AuthorizeAttribute` as you suggested. I had contemplated it before, but wanted to eliminate the possibility of using existing attribute beforehand.